# android fragment top bar difference between devices

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have many fragments in my application Like [image: this]

and it's worked very well on **MarshiMello** as above, but in other device there is top bar I don't know how to remove it ...?

[image]

Comment: its fragmentdialog or dialog activity?

Comment: @KeyurThumar fragmentdialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to remove title.

```
@Override
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    // request a window without the title
 dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 return dialog;
}
```